# Linux filesystem permissions

Tags: linux, filesystems, permissions

If I have this folder:
/var/username/secret/
that is 770, then can a file in /var/username/secret/file that is 0777 be read/written by anyone on that same server (shared hosting)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is your directory permission: 770 won't allow 'others' to get access to the directory

Answer (score 1):

Only user and group from "secret" directory can "CD" to it. So other users can't go inside the dir and can't use file.